# Preventing data injection with htmlspecialchars() function

Tags: php, html, forms, xss, code-injection

Many documents recommend to use htmlspecialchars() to get rid of data injection during form submitting.
[form-validation](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp).

With html5 (i guess) not using action attribute of form, makes the similar effect with using `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`. Does actionless forms create the same security leak as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you make actionless form, you don't use **$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]**, so its safe.